# How can I make a DIV fullscreen in Blazor Server app on button click?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, blazor

In my new Blazor application I have a table with real live weather data. I want to have a button which puts the table or the div that encapsulates this table to go fullscreen. It would be really easy by using Javascript, but I'm new to Blazor so I don't know how to make it work with C#.

Any ideas?

```
[BUTTON]
<button id="forecastbuttonfullscreen" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="fullscreenforecast"> Fullscreen forecast </button>



<div class ="weathercontainer">
<table class="Weathertable">
<tr>
                <td>"2022-03-12"</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="icon sunny">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td> "-10"  °</td>
                <td> "-2"  °</td>
            </tr>
</table>
</div>

@code {

    private void fullscreenforecast()
    {
       ?????
    }

}
```

Comment: So as to understand exactly what you want, how would you do it in JS?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54087863/how-to-change-classes-of-a-div-element-using-blazor) shows you how to modify render of HTML directly or only classes. You can use the same logic by setting a boolean in `fullscreenforecast()`. Then it will be an HTML/CSS issue.

Comment: Here is an official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-6.0) about using js in blazor.